# Iron-router and notFoundTemplate

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This is my route:

```
this.route('showItem', {
  path: '/item/:_id',
  template: 'layout',
  yieldTemplates: {
      'content': {to: 'content'},
      'item_details': {to: 'details'}
  },
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  data: function () {
      return null; //for test
  }
})
```

And `notFound` template, it's simple:

```
<template name="notFound">

   Not found!

</template>
```

And I can't understand, why always renders `item_details` and never `notFound`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was Iron-Router 0.7 they added a requirement where you had to switch on global hooks:

```
Router.onBeforeAction("dataNotFound");
```

This is the one for not found templates. There is a bit of info on it on [this issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/610). The reasoning behind this change is that you can customize the functions that decide whether data is found or not.

Comment: Thanks! Now working, but... :-) Is it possible render`notFound` exactly instead `item_details`? Because my `content` - map with markers. I don't want redraw the map, only details section